# Sorting files by “line content” frequency - print duplicates

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, sorting, uniq

Imagine there is a file -

```
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
d
d
d
```

I want the output to be sorted based on frequency (I want the duplicate lines to be printed as well) as -

```
b
b
b
b
d
d
d
c
c
a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU Awk:

```
gawk '
   { arr[$0]++ }
   END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (ln in arr) for (i = 1; i <= arr[ln]; i++) print ln
       }
   '
```

The trick is to use an array and `@val_num_desc`. Every encountered line becomes an index, the associated value is increased each time the line appears. At the end we scan the entire array in a specific order:

> `"@val_num_desc"`
>   […] the element values, treated as numbers, are ordered from high to low.

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)

So the outer (first) `for` is responsible for retrieving lines and their frequencies in the desired order; the inner (second) `for` is just to print the currently picked line the right number of times.

Note:

- Every character matters. A line and the same line with an extra trailing space are different.

Comment: `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` - awesome, just what I was looking for to make an `awk` example too, thanks!

Comment: @Attie I think it may not work in plain `awk`, unless your `awk` is `gawk` in disguise. In my Debian `awk` used to be too limited, I had to install `gawk`. Now both commands understand this because `awk` is (non-directly) symlinked to `gawk`.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do what you're after... though there are many other ways to achieve this... for example with `gawk`, as per Kamil's answer.

- The first `sort` will order the data by line data
- `uniq -c` will count the number of matching occurrences (they must be neighbours)
- `sort -nr` will sort by the number of occurrences, in reverse order
- The `while` loop iterates over each line

  - `read n l` will ingest the count into `n`, and the line data into `l`
- The `for` loop will iterate `n` times
- `echo "${l}"` outputs the line data

```bsh
(
    sort \
        | uniq -c \
        | sort -nr \
        | while read n l; do \
            for i in $(seq ${n}); do \
                echo "${l}"; \
            done; \
        done
) <<"EOF"
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
d
d
d
EOF
```